# SAS: create new column based on regex logical statement

Tags: regex, sas

I have a large dataset where one column contains free text. I wish to create a new column based on whether this free text contains a regular expression.

Eg:
I want to know whether this column contains the text GnRH, or those letters in any case, and create a new column with a flag to indicate if this is true or not.

Comment: What do you mean by 'Or those letters in any case' ?

Comment: match GnRH, GNRH, gnrh, gNRH, or those letters regardless or capital or lower case.

Answer (score 3):

[FIND](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/ds2ref/n1v0tzf4xq363mn15mnppqtk2zti.htm) or [INDEX](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/ds2ref/p11iz7be9jz1jkn1jmzehaghm09y.htm) work as well, and slightly easier to understand.

```
DUMMY = find(text, "gnrh", 'it') > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
data have;
input text $20.;
datalines;
Not in this line  
In GnRH this line 
Not here either   
This one GNRH too 
;

data want;
   set have;
   dummy = prxmatch('/gnrh/i', text) > 0;
run;
```